# Optimizing the Spark Code

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to improve my Spark code:

```
var lst = disOneRDDM.filter(x=> x._2._1 == 1).keys.collect
val disTwoRDDM = disOneRDDM.map(x=> {
                                    var b:Boolean = false
                                    breakable{
                                    for (str <- x._2._2)
                                       if (lst.contains(str))
                                            {b = true
                                            break}
                                    }
                                    if (b)
                                        (x._1,(Math.min(2,x._2._1),x._2._2))
                                    else
                                        x
                                   }).cache
```

I have RDD's of the form (String,(Int,List[String])). Every element in the `List[String]` has its own entry in this RDD where it serves as a key. A sample input is shown below (this is the `disOneRDDM` in my code):

```
("abc",(10,List("hij","efg","klm")))
("efg",(1,List("jhg","Beethan","abc","ert")))
("Beethan",(0,List("efg","vcx","zse")))
("vcx",(1,List("czx","Beethan","abc")))
("zse",(1,List("efg","Beethan","nbh")))
("hij",(10,List("vcx","klm","zse")))
("jhg",(10,List("ghb","cdz","awq","swq")))
...
```

My intent is to find in each of the `List[String]` an element which has the `Int` value of 1 and and change its own `Int` to `min(2,current_Int_value)`. For example in the input code the entry `"abc"` has the list which contains `"efg"` as an element which has `Int` value 1 and also entry `"hij"` has `"vcx"`. So I would expect an output of the form:

```
("abc",(2,List("hij","efg","klm")))
("efg",(1,List("jhg","Beethan","abc","ert")))
("Beethan",(0,List("efg","vcx","zse")))
("vcx",(1,List("czx","Beethan","abc")))
("zse",(1,List("efg","Beethan","nbh")))
("hij",(2,List("vcx","klm","zse")))
("jhg",(10,List("ghb","cdz","awq","swq")))
...
```

The size of the RDD is huge and the way I am doing it works but is very slow. In the code above, I am trying to filter the RDD which has `Int` value 1 and form the list `lst` by collecting them. Then for finding elements which have `Int` value 2, I am iterating over the element's list entries and check if the list `lst` contains the entry. If it does, I break out of loop and assign the appropriate `Int` value.
Is there a faster way to do it, for example without having to collect the huge RDD in list?

Comment: lst is a list that comes from an RDD so I'm assuming its somewhat sizable. What you're doing is iterating through it for every single row in disOneRDDM. Also its not broadcasted so for every single partition in the map the list is getting serialized and distributed. I'd convert lst to a Set and broadcast it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @a-spoty-spot commented, if there aren't too many *unique* values of `lst` - your best approach is to change it to `Set` (which removes duplicates) and use broadcast.

Otherwise (if that list of unique keys can still be huge) - here's a solution that doesn't use `collect` at all, which means it can handle any size. However - since it increases the size of the RDD by using `flatMap` and performs a `join` (which entails a shuffle), I'm not sure it would be much faster, that depends on the specifics of your data and your cluster.

```
// create the lookup "map" (the int values are actually irrelevant, we just need the keys)
val lookup: RDD[(String, Int)] = disOneRDDM.cache().filter(_._2._1 == 1).map(t => (t._1, 1))

val result = disOneRDDM
  .flatMap { // break up each record into individual records for join
    case (k, (i, list)) => list.map(s => (s, (k, i)))
  }
  .leftOuterJoin(lookup).map { // left join with lookup and change int values if we found a match
    case (item, ((k, i), Some(_))) => (k, (Math.min(2, i), item))
    case (item, ((k, i), _)) => (k, (i, item))
  }
  .groupByKey().map { // group by key to merge back to lists, while mapping to the desired structure
    case (k, iter) =>
      val l = iter.toList
      (k, (l.map(_._1).min, l.map(_._2)))
  }

result.foreach(println)
// (Beethan,(0,List(zse, efg, vcx)))
// (jhg,(10,List(cdz, swq, ghb, awq)))
// (hij,(2,List(klm, zse, vcx)))
// (zse,(1,List(Beethan, nbh, efg)))
// (efg,(1,List(Beethan, jhg, abc, ert)))
// (vcx,(1,List(Beethan, czx, abc)))
// (abc,(2,List(klm, hij, efg)))
```

Comment: added another answer using Dataframes, which I find a bit cleaner, but both are valid.

Comment: Just a quick question, will broadcasting help if I am using a single node for my computation?

Comment: Yes, I think so - when not using broadcast, data is serialized and sent per _task_, so you might still pay a higher overhead even if you're using a single node.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use Dataframes API instead of RDDs - here's another option which might simplify the code a bit (and improve performance):

```
// UDF to check if string contained in array - will be used for the join
val arrayContains = udf { (a: mutable.WrappedArray[String], s: String) => a.contains(s) }

// create Dataframe from RDD and create the filtered lookupDF
val df = disOneRDDM.map {case (k, (v, l)) => (k, v, l) }.toDF("key", "val", "list").cache()
val lookupDf = df.filter($"val" === 1).select($"key" as "match")

// join, groupBy to remove the duplicates while collecting non-null matches, and perform transformation on "val"
val resultDF = df
.join(lookupDf, arrayContains($"list", $"match"), "leftouter")
.groupBy($"key").agg(
  first("val") as "val",
  first("list") as "list",
  first("match", ignoreNulls = true) as "match")
.selectExpr("key", "IF(match IS NULL OR val < 2, val, 2) as val", "list")

resultDF.show()
// +-------+---+--------------------+
// |    key|val|                list|
// +-------+---+--------------------+
// |    zse|  1| [efg, Beethan, nbh]|
// |    efg|  1|[jhg, Beethan, ab...|
// |    hij|  2|     [vcx, klm, zse]|
// |Beethan|  0|     [efg, vcx, zse]|
// |    vcx|  1| [czx, Beethan, abc]|
// |    abc|  2|     [hij, efg, klm]|
// |    jhg| 10|[ghb, cdz, awq, swq]|
// +-------+---+--------------------+
```